# Too many errors, example... <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uidatepicker

I am using a datepicker as the input view to my UITableViewCell.  However, sometimes, I am receiving a lot of error stack trace with "invalid context 0x0".

Am I doing it the wrong way?  I am developing in iOS7 using latest XCode.

```
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
self.datePickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
[self.datePickerToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
UIBarButtonItem *extraSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setDatePickerValue:)];
[self.datePickerToolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:extraSpace, doneButton, nil]];

self.dateTableViewCellTextField.inputView = self.datePicker;
self.dateTableViewCellTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.datePickerToolbar;
```

Comment: Where is this code? Do you call `drawRect:` or a `CGContext` somewhere?

Comment: No, I am not calling any of those, that's why I am kinda surprised with the errors.  They are all CGContext***

Comment: Add some logs / break points to your code to localise where the log is being generated.

Comment: Is there something that starts off as a CGRectZero and remains that way? . . I think I've seen this when a UIView with CGRectZero frame tries to animate.

Comment: the thing is, the errors doesn't come all the time, so it's hard to debug.  I am not using any class starting CGRect*** in any of my codes in my whole project except this CGRectMake.
the application is still running and didn't crash. however, i am afraid once i submit this code to apple because of these too many errors in the log

Comment: I got the same bug with a textfield in a `UIAlertView`. Try setting an empty string for your textfield before you populate it with data. From what I've read, might be an iOS7 bug. `self.dateTableViewCellTextField.text = @"";`